# Converting string containing binary to unsigned and signed ints

Tags: c++, binary, unsigned-integer, std-bitset

I want to write program (at the moment I don't have any code), which should do the following:

1. Take from user string containing binary number,
2. **Convert it to `unsigned int` and `signed int`,**
3. Return the result to the user.

**How can I implement the second activity?** I'm looking for any help.

Comment: So - user gives you zeros and ones, and you have to pack it to `int`?

Comment: I already have it in a variable... I'm just not sure what to do after that.

Comment: What do you want to do with the data?

Comment: Just convert the binary to unsigned and signed integers and return it to the user.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "binary?" Can you give an example code where you'll encapsulate the missing functionality in a declared but not defined function, so that we can see the input/output format you expect?

Comment: I think you should read some about bitwise operators, if you want implement it yourself.

Comment: I need to write a program in any language that takes as its input a string of either 16 or 32 binary digits that then takes that string and converts it into an unsigned and signed int.

Comment: I suggest you write the program in LISP or SNOBOL.  This should be challenging as neither language has implicit facilities for handling bits.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you develop your own algorithm using pen and paper:

```
For each digit in string do:
  value = digit - '0'; convert from text to internal representation.
  binary number <<= 1; Move the existing bits left by one to make room.
  binary number |= value;  put the digit into the binary number.
  right shift string.
end-for.
```

Or you can write your own code, test it and debug it, then if you have any questions, post them (along with the code) as a new question.